# How to blur background of body when the navbar is opened in mobile

Tags: html, css, navbar, blur

I have a navbar and as soon as I opened it on mobile I want background blur as you see in the picture.
[image]

here is my navbar:

```
<!--navigation-->
    <section class="smart-scroll">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand heading-black" href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo" />CineFi.Network
          </a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span data-feather="grid"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#projects">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#staking">Staking</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#cine-token"
                  >Cine Token</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#register">Register</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#login">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#connect-wallet"
                  >Connect Wallet</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
```

And my cs for navbar:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  #navbarCollapse {
    background-color: #29292a;
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }
}
```

I didn't post the rest of the css for the navbar in the desktop but if you think it is necessary I can edit my question.I apply blur but first I need to blur it when the navbar is opened and second I need to blur whole body, so that's what I dont know how to do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur()

Comment: Use `backdrop-filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: I need to blur only when I opened the navbar, that's why I asked this question